# How do I check to see if my array is in ascending order?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, shuffle

So I have an array board[][] whose values keep shuffling around. It is a square array with dimensions d*d. I want to check the array to see if all of its values are in ascending order.

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][j] == (d * i) + j + 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that as soon as the first element in the array board[0][0] = 1, it returns true, and ends my code. I don't know how to implement it so that it doesn't return true until all the elements in the array are in ascending order, from 1 to (d*d - 1).

Thank you!

Comment: The bounds in your second `for` loop seem completely wrong. SO is not a site for code review, and even if it was, you'd be supposed to have done a minimal debugging on it.

Comment: First, that second loop should check and increase `j`, rather than `i`. Then, as long as the items are in correct order, you must not break from the loop (`return true`), but continue to the end of your board, and `return true` from after the loop.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly I think you want to do this:

```
int Previous = board[0][0];
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
    {
        if (board[i][j] < Previous)
        {
            return false;
        }

        Previous = board[i][j];
    }
}
return true; // Only at the end do we know that all elements are in ascending order
```

Problems with what you have are:

1. You are returning on either condition instead of returning after all values have been checked
2. Your second for loop is wrong and references i, not j
3. Your comparison is comparing `board` values against the indexes, not other `board` values

Comment: It seems that all the elements should be exactly from 1 to (d*d)-1.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < d; j++)
    {
        if (board[i][j] != (d * i) + j + 1)
        {
           return false;
        }
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `return true` with `continue`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; i < d; i++)
    {
        if (board[i][j] == (d * i) + j + 1)
        {
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also remove the continue clause completely if you reverse the condition:

```
        if (board[i][j] != (d * i) + j + 1)
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) First what you mean by ascending order (vertically, horizontally or in diagonal ?)
2) Replace your if statement
if ((board[i][j] > board[i][j+1]) || (board[i][j] > board[i+1][j]))